# Why Android Studio don't propose certain suggestions in code completion

Tags: flutter, android-studio

This code:

[image]

shape is of type `MaterialStateProperty<OutlineBorder?>` so why when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> `MaterialStateProperty` is not directly proposed in the list of suggestions, even if I start to type Ma...

[image]

I do not understand why...